# Stochastic Differential of $e^{B(t)-\frac{1}{2}t}$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Stochastic processes beginner here!

So I'm trying to find the stochastic differential of $e^{B_t-\frac{1}{2}t}$

Ito's formula applied to $f[t, B_t]$, a function of time and Brownian motion, yields:

$$df=\frac{df}{dt}dt+\frac{df}{dB_t}dB_t+\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}(dt)^2+\frac{d^2f}{dtdB_t}dtdB_t+\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2f}{dB_t^2}(dB_t)^2$$

where, 
$$(dt)^2=0;dtdB_t=0;(dB_t)^2=dt,$$
and
$$\begin{align}
\frac{df}{dt}&=-\frac{1}{2}e^{B_t-\frac{1}{2}t}\\
\frac{df}{dB_t}&=e^{B_t-\frac{1}{2}t}\\
\frac{d^2f}{dB_t^2}&=e^{B_t-\frac{1}{2}t}
\end{align}$$

Subbing into the equation: 
$$\begin{align}
d\left(e^{B_t-\frac{1}{2}t}\right)&=-\frac{1}{2}e^{B_t-\frac{1}{2}t}dt+e^{B_t-\frac{1}{2}t}dB_t+\frac{1}{2}e^{B_t-\frac{1}{2}t}dt\\
&=e^{B_t-\frac{1}{2}t}dB_t
\end{align}$$

Is my process and answer correct? Many thanks!

Comment: The final solution is correct. But writing this is incorrect: $\dfrac{df}{dB}dB$, write instead $\dfrac{df}{dx}dB_t$. You cannot derive according to a random variable that is why you use Ito Lemma. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma

Comment: @Zizou23 Thank you, and thank you for the tip!